# Constructor injection in data class

Tags: spring, kotlin, dependency-injection

I'm trying the following:

```
@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
data class MyValueConfig(
    @Value("\${my.value1}") var value1: Int? = null,
    @Value("\${my.value2}") var value2: String? = null,
    @Value("\${my.value3}") var value3: String? = null
)
```

Spring does not wire the value fields, they are null.
Because Spring needs a default constructor my assumption was that I could provide it like this. Hence, the nullable types.

This works because it is based on setter injection:

```
@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
class MyValueConfig {
    @Value("\${my.value}") lateinit var value1: Int = 0   
    @Value("\${my.value2}") lateinit var value2: String
    @Value("\${my.value3}") lateinit var value3: String
}
```

Is it possible to use constructor injection in kotlin using the `data class`?

Comment: Please take a look on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 0):

To have a constructor injection on data classes use the `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor

```
@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
data class MyValueConfig @Autowired constructor(
    @Value("\${my.value1}") var value1: Int? = null,
    @Value("\${my.value2}") var value2: String? = null,
    @Value("\${my.value3}") var value3: String? = null
)
```